# How to make smooth onscroll effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, smoothing

I need to make the scroll the same as here:

https://forner.studio/

https://synchronized.studio/

As you can see, both websites are very smooth while scrolling.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Or you can add this with javascript in three different ways, depending on your need:

```
// goes to specific height position at 2500 pixels:
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

// scrolls 100 pixels from the current position:
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// scrolls to an element with class .hello:
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```